How to get the parent Query Id and root Id in Snowflake?
I have written a script that retrieves the status of all procedures, including any child procedures executed within a parent procedure. The script works correctly when all child procedures complete successfully. However, it fails to capture and populate details if any child procedure encounters a failure.
The steps my script follows are:

It identifies the procedure name.
It checks the query history for all relevant details of the procedure.
It also queries the access history to capture any child procedures or associated queries and corresponding Parent and Root Query Id.

The issue seems to be that access history only retains data for queries that have successfully completed. My requirement is to obtain the parent or root query ID, regardless of whether the query succeeded or failed. If a procedure has run, it should be visible in the results, irrespective of its outcome.
How can I modify my approach to achieve this?
Script
    WITH PARENT_RUN AS (
    SELECT
    Q.QUERY_ID,
    Q.QUERY_TEXT,
    Q.DATABASE_NAME AS RUN_DB,
    Q.SCHEMA_NAME AS RUN_SCHEMA,
    Q.QUERY_TYPE,
    Q.SESSION_ID,
    Q.USER_NAME,
    Q.ROLE_NAME,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_NAME,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_SIZE,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_TYPE,
    Q.QUERY_TAG,
    Q.EXECUTION_STATUS,
    Q.ERROR_CODE,
    Q.ERROR_MESSAGE,
    Q.START_TIME,
    Q.END_TIME,
    Q.EXECUTION_TIME,
    Q.COMPILATION_TIME,
    Q.QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME,
    A.PARENT_QUERY_ID,
    A.ROOT_QUERY_ID
    FROM
        SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY Q
    JOIN SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY A
    ON Q.QUERY_ID = A.QUERY_ID
    WHERE
        Q.QUERY_TYPE = 'CALL'
            AND (Q.QUERY_TEXT ILIKE 'CALL <parent Proc Name>(%')
        AND Q.START_TIME > '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    ),
    CHILD_QUERY_ID AS (
        SELECT
            A.QUERY_ID,
        FROM PARENT_RUN Q
        JOIN SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY A
        ON Q.QUERY_ID = A.PARENT_QUERY_ID OR Q.QUERY_ID = A.ROOT_QUERY_ID
    ),
    CHILD_RUN AS (
    SELECT
    Q.QUERY_ID,
    Q.QUERY_TEXT,
    Q.DATABASE_NAME AS RUN_DB,
    Q.SCHEMA_NAME AS RUN_SCHEMA,
    Q.QUERY_TYPE,
    Q.SESSION_ID,
    Q.USER_NAME,
    Q.ROLE_NAME,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_NAME,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_SIZE,
    Q.WAREHOUSE_TYPE,
    Q.QUERY_TAG,
    Q.EXECUTION_STATUS,
    Q.ERROR_CODE,
    Q.ERROR_MESSAGE,
    Q.START_TIME,
    Q.END_TIME,
    Q.EXECUTION_TIME,
    Q.COMPILATION_TIME,
    Q.QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME,
    A.PARENT_QUERY_ID,
    A.ROOT_QUERY_ID
    FROM
        SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY Q
    JOIN SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY A
    ON Q.QUERY_ID = A.QUERY_ID
    JOIN CHILD_QUERY_ID C
    ON Q.QUERY_ID = C.QUERY_ID
    WHERE
        Q.QUERY_TYPE = 'CALL' AND Q.START_TIME >  '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    ),
    FINAL_AUDIT AS (
        SELECT * FROM PARENT_RUN
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM CHILD_RUN
    )

    SELECT 
        QUERY_ID,
        QUERY_TEXT,
        START_TIME,
        END_TIME,
        EXECUTION_TIME,
        EXECUTION_STATUS,
        QUERY_TYPE,
        SESSION_ID,
        USER_NAME,
        ROLE_NAME,
        WAREHOUSE_NAME,
        WAREHOUSE_SIZE,
        WAREHOUSE_TYPE,
        QUERY_TAG,
        ERROR_CODE,
        ERROR_MESSAGE,
        RUN_DB,
        RUN_SCHEMA,
        PROCEDURE_FQN,
        COMPILATION_TIME,
        QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME,
        PARENT_QUERY_ID,
        ROOT_QUERY_ID,
    FROM FINAL_AUDIT 


I’m not sure I would approach the problem like that. Assuming that your starting point is a call to a stored procedure, then everything executed by that stored procedure will have the same session id as the SP and will start/end within the start/end period of the SP - so just query based on that

Yes I am using session id only for a workaround

Only issue with session id will be if someone calling the stored procedure from Snowflake worksheet then session will be same for all query

Yes, but as sessions can’t run queries in parallel, anything running between the start and end time of the SP call must be a child query of that SP

The problem has been solved with new view that Snowflake has recently provided. Below is the answer   @NickW
